# Geocoding - Different Postal Code In Response

Tags: google-geocoding-api, postal-code

I am using the geocoding API passing postal codes (GB mainly) to validate if the postal code is valid or not (using the address_components and types where if it returns "postal_code" I take that it is valid) but I have found 2 issues.

Also is this the best method with Google Maps to validate a postal code?

1. I am posting https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=GU27YP&components=country:GB&key= where the postal code of GU2 7YP is sent and in the response it is giving me a different postal code (GU2 7UP). Why is this doing this, is it telling me that the postal code no longer exists (in 2016 it was removed) and now this other 1 has replaced it?

"address_components": [
{
"long_name": "GU2 7UP",
"short_name": "GU2 7UP",
"types": [
"postal_code"
]
},

2. I am validating postal code OL1 1NY (GB) and it returns a positive result but the postal code is no longer recognised by Royal Mail and was removed in Dec 2022. Is there a way to get Google to update it?

"address_components": [
{
"long_name": "OL1 1NY",
"short_name": "OL1 1NY",
"types": [
"postal_code"
]
},

For both issues I was expecting that would give me a response without a postal code match and would state the below as it does for another invalid postal code of ME4 4QQ

```
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "United Kingdom",
                "short_name": "GB",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/architecture/geocoding-address-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#component-filtering) is probably a better approach, at least it will prevent *false positive* results, e.g. returning GU2 7UP when requesting GU2 7YP:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:GB|postal_code:GU2%207YP](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:GB%7Cpostal_code:GU2%207YP) returns `ZERO_RESULTS` because the `components` parameter *enforces an exact match* on `postal_code:GU2%207YP`

Whether a result is returned or not depends mostly on Google Maps data being accurate and up to date.

Another option could be using the new [Address Validation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation) which *broadly speaking* provides 2 different "results":

1. `address`: how much of the input is confirmed to be (part of) a valid postal address
2. `geocode`: where would Google Maps locate the input (may or **may not** match the `address`).

More details in [Understand the validation response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/understand-response).

As an example, the [Address Validation Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/demo) returns an `address` that essentially says "yes, GU2 7YP is a valid UK postal code", but the `geocode` returned is in fact GU2 7**U**P (Place ID: [ChIJm7gwBcLQdUgRSfAroiN7KYw](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJm7gwBcLQdUgRSfAroiN7KYw)) because that's the (closet) one available.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing component filtering is a recommended strategy, as it minimizes incorrect results—like retrieving GU2 7UP when the goal is GU2 7YP.
For instance, the link:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:GB%7Cpostal_code:GU2%207YP
yields ZERO_RESULTS due to its insistence on a precise match for postal_code:GU2%207YP.
The success of getting the desired result largely leans on the precision and currentness of Google Maps' data.